# Count Same Records VB.NET\Access

Tags: vb.net

My question is:
I add new user in Access Database.
If Users with entered tabNum is already exists - you see messagebox.
But i've error in code:
This code always shows message `Record with this TabNum already exists!` and value of K is always equal to 1.

Can you help me find errors in my code?

```
 Dim k As Integer = 0
    Dim Con2 As New OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.oledb.12.0; Data source=" + bpath) 
    Dim SqlCom2 As OleDb.OleDbCommand 
    SqlCom2 = New OleDb.OleDbCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [Users] WHERE [TabNum] = @T1", Con2) 
    SqlCom2.Parameters.Add("@T1", OleDbType.WChar).Value = usadm.DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(0).Value
    Con2.Open() 
    SqlCom2.ExecuteNonQuery() 
    k = SqlCom2.ExecuteScalar()
    If k > 0 Then
        MsgBox("Record with this TabNum already exists!")
```

Comment: try replacing your code by `k = Convert.ToInt32SqlCom2.ExecuteScalar())`

Comment: Please show the connection string part that it is hidden in your variable `bpath`. Are you using the `|DataDirectory|` shortcut?

Comment: No, bpath as string="C:\database.accdb"